# Cannot convert value of type '() -> _' to specified type '[UIViewController]'

Tags: ios, swift

this error is appear in my code as below :-

the code is :-

```
class EveningPageViewController: UIPageViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource {
    lazy var viewControllerList2: [UIViewController] = {

    let sorbord = UIStoryboard(name : "main", bundle:nil)
```

the error is :-

> Cannot convert value of type '() -> _' to specified type
>   '[UIViewController]'

Comment: You need [edit] your question to include all relevant code in the form of a [mcve].

Comment: There is nothing returned from your closure, and definitely not an array of view controllers.

Comment: You forgot to put the return [vc1, vc2, vc3, ..., vcN]}() at the end of the block!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You declare the viewControllerList2 as an array of UIViewControllers.

Then you try to set a code of block to that var! That is your problem.
You are doing this:

```
lazy var viewControllerList2: [UIViewController] 
viewControllerList2 = {
    let sorbord = UIStoryboard(name : "main", bundle:nil)
}
```

That is equal to do something like this:

```
var myString: String
myString = 4
```

You are changing the variable type!!!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/4685823/gastón-antonio-montes
the best answer was useful for my code
gastón-antonio-montes ; many thanks for you